# Chrome all of a sudden zoomed in on ubuntu

Tags: linux, google-chrome, ubuntu

My chrome browser is all of a sudden really zoomed in on my ubuntu system. Not not page content where I can easy control the zoom - but the actual browser!

Does anyone know what is going on? I am on the normal 1920x1080 resolution - but my browser must be thinking it is on 100x100 or something!

It is the only program that is super zoomed in.

Any tips would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue in Chrome 43.0.2357.124 for Linux.  It is fixed as of Chrome 43.0.2357.125.  See [this issue in their bug tracker](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=498426), opened 2 days ago (June 9 2015).  You should update Chrome to the latest version:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install --only-upgrade google-chrome-stable
```

If updating Chrome isn't an option, you can open Chrome with some command-line arguments: Start chrome from terminal like this:

```
google-chrome --high-dpi-support=1 --force-device-scale-factor=1
```

This works for me on Ubuntu 14.10.

Answer (score 0):

This is bug in Chrome.

You can try running Chrome with the following flags:

```
google-chrome --high-dpi-support=1 --force-device-scale-factor=1
```

Here's a reddit thread: https://www.reddit.com/r/chrome/comments/399cle/chrome_suddenly_low_resolution_large_tabs_and/

And a Chrome Help Forum thread:
https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/fHwvtcxEiDo

Comment: Welcome To Stack Overflow! Instead of pasting a link to a solution, you should also add the relevant code from the link in your answer.  That way if the link ever goes down the answer is still available.